# How to populate a check box list in asp.net Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to figure out how to populate a check box list in asp.net Core Razor Pages. Consider the following classes:

```
public class SignupPageModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<CheckBoxGroup> Hobbies{ get; set; }
}

public class CheckBoxGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then from the`Page` I want to populate the `Hobbies` list from a database (code snippets edited for simplicity):

```
public class SignupModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public SignupPageModel Input { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var model = new SignupPageModel();
        model.Hobbies = _repo.GetHobbiesCheckBoxGroup();
    }
}
```

And display in the view:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Input.Hobbies.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Input.Hobbies[i].IsSelected"/>
        <label asp-for="@Model.Input.Hobbies[i].IsSelected">@Model.Input.Hobbies[i].Name</label>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Input.Hobbies[i].Id"/>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Input.Hobbies[i].Name"/>
    </div>
 }
```

But when rendering the `View` I get the following error:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

On this line:

`@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Input.Hobbies.Count; i++)`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this same problem, the fix was to change:

```
public class SignupModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public SignupPageModel Input { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var model = new SignupPageModel();
        model.Hobbies = _repo.GetHobbiesCheckBoxGroup();
    }
}
```

To this:

```
public class SignupModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public SignupPageModel Input { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Input = new SignupPageModel();
        Input.Hobbies = _repo.GetHobbiesCheckBoxGroup();
    }
}
```